# Can't browse to any website though I can ping

Tags: networking, internet, website

This is got me.

**This is a Windows 7 Machine**

I am trying to fix a computer for a user REMOTELY(yes I can RDC to it)
In any browser(FF, IE, Chrome) I cannot connect to any web page externally.

Things I tried:

- DNS IS resolving properly via ping, I cannot browse to sites even using their IP address in the browser.
- I ran pretty much every AV I can: Vipre, SuperAntiSpyware, Malware Bytes, MDSS Killer, ComboFix
- I ran fixers: WINSOCKSFIX(or something like that), Little Registry Cleaner.
- I reset the WinSH settings and logs.
- There is NO proxy set, nor should there be.
- The hosts file is default.

I'm kidna lost at this point, any ideas anyone?

Comment: Port 80 may be blocked

Comment: Wait, so what are you doing? Are you opening the browser on your computer or the remote computer?

Comment: What do you see in the browser?  Is there an error message?  If so, what is it?

Comment: The firewall it is behind is not blocking 80, and computers next to it can connect fine.

I am opening the browser on the remote computer.

The error is "Page cannot be displayed" in IE and "This webpage is not available" in Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was an issue with an incorrect uninstall of "Bonjour" which came with one of Mac's programs that was uninstalled but did not uninstall properly. I had to manually remove these entries from the registry.